# jsTree - render all nodes before they are expanded?

Tags: jquery, nodes, jstree, children

I'm trying to display the titles of all descendants of a jsTree parent in a separate div (.childNodes) when an item is selected in the tree. My issue is that the descendants are seemingly being lazy loaded, and are only rendered in the DOM when a node is expanded, not when it is selected. Is there a way to disable this to render all nodes before the parent is expanded?

This is how I'm creating the tree:

```
container.jstree({
'core': {
    'data': {
        'url': nodesContent,
    }
}});
```

And this is how I'm handling the selected event:

```
container.on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
var i,
    list = "<ul>";
var children = data.instance.get_children_dom(data.selected[0]);
for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    list += "<li>" + children[i].innerHTML + "</li>";
}
list += "</ul>";
jQuery(".childNodes").html(list);});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it can not be disabled - only visible nodes are kept in the DOM, you can however do what is recommended in the docs and work with the internal jstree model to retrieve the titles.

```
container.on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
    var i,
        list = "<ul>";
        children = data.instance.get_node(data.selected[0]).children;
    for (i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        list += "<li>" + data.instance.get_node(children[i]).text + "</li>";
    }
    list += "</ul>";
    jQuery(".childNodes").html(list);
});
```

If you want to display all descendants (not only immediate) substitute:
`data.instance.get_node(data.selected[0]).children`
with:
`data.instance.get_node(data.selected[0]).children_d`